# Selecting an object from a ListView in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a ListView that contains "Task "objects. I want to be able to select a task from the ListView and get the values of that specific object. I am trying to do this by calling a method (startTask()) that gets the selected item in the ListView (a task object) and gets its values by using the getter methods in the task object. For the moment i am just printing the object to the console.

When I run the application this is the error that I get.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Brian.Nora-PC/workspace/TaskApp/bin/application/taskapp.fxml:63

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at application.Main.start(Main.java:20)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to coerce #startTask() to interface javafx.event.EventHandler.
at com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.coerce(BeanAdapter.java:496)
at com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.put(BeanAdapter.java:258)
at com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.put(BeanAdapter.java:54)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.applyProperty(FXMLLoader.java:512)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:363)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processPropertyAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:325)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processInstancePropertyAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:235)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:767)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
... 17 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

Here is the fxml file that contains the ListView and Button with startTask() method call when the button is clicked

```
<Tab text="Tasks">
  <content>
    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
    <children>
     <Label fx:id="noOfTasks" layoutX="403.0" layoutY="294.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="190.0" text="You have 0 tasks to be completed" />
              <ListView fx:id="taskList" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="274.0" prefWidth="585.0" />
              <Button layoutX="8.0" layoutY="299.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Start Task" OnAction="#startTask()"/>
    </children>

    </AnchorPane>
  </content>
</Tab>
```

Here is the startTask() method

```
public void startTask(){
    Task taskToStart = taskList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println(taskToStart);



}
```

Here is my initialisation of ListView in Controller.java

```
public ListView<Task> taskList = new ListView<Task>();
```

Any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: First of all, if you have defined a ListView in the FXML file, you shouldn't overwrite the injected instance with a `new ListView` later on. Second, can you display the entire error? It's cut off at the moment

Comment: Can you also include what your imports are for this file?

Comment: Ok thanks ill get rid of that now. Yes ill put up the whole stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying controller methods as event handlers requires you to use a `#` followed by the method's name **and nothing else** (see also [*Introduction to FXML - Controller Method Event Handlers*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controller_method_event_handlers) ). Remove the `()` from the `onAction` attribute:

```xml
<Button layoutX="8.0" layoutY="299.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Start Task" onAction="#startTask"/>
```

Furthermore there should be no need to initialize the `ListView` using a constructor call in the code, if you inject it from the fxml; Furthermore a `ListView` created using a constructor call won't insert itself to the scene. It's likely that you just create a second `ListView` that is never shown. Instead there should be a `ListView` field with the name `taskList` in the controller class; this field should not be initialized from java code:

```
@FXML
private ListView<Task> taskList;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help I changed that but it still didnt but that was only because i had named the onAction attribute incorrectly. I called it OnAction. I switch to onAction and the program works. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this...

```
ObservableList<Node> list=taskList.getChildren();
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {   
    Task task=list.get(i);
}
```